# How to avoid JQuery conflict?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

For my ajax operations when the ajax working properly table features not loading.

I using to my table operation :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
         src="Dia_tables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
         src="Dia_tables/examples_support/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
         src="Dia_tables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Javascript :

```
<script src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js></script>
<script type="javascript">
    jQuery17 = jQuery.noConfict(true);
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        var username = $('#user').val();
        var userk = $('#phone').val();
        $.get('test', {
            user: username,
            phone: userk
        }, function (responseText) {
            $('textarea#welcometext').text(responseText);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan -am using jquery-latest.min.js for ajax opration with out that jquery  it is not working

Comment: You shuld use jquery-latest.min.js ONLY ! if u use 10 versions of jQuery , some code wil work , other wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {                        
               jq('#submit').click(function(event) {  
                    var username=jq('#user').val();
                    var userk=jq('#phone').val();
                 jq.get('test',{user:username,phone:userk},function(responseText) { 
                        jq('textarea#welcometext').text(responseText);         
                    });
                });
            });
```